# How to register new JNDI name at run time by our program?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jndi

Is there any way to create/register new JNDI name at run time in JBoss from our java class?
Want to add new Queue on newly created JNDI name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bind method of [InitialContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) to register new objects in JNDI tree.